# Call to backend works properly inside service, but not outside service

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, observable

I'm trying to make a call to my backed, and it returns data just fine inside of my service, but when I try to use that service in a different module, it either logs `undefined` or `Observable`. Can anyone point me in a good direction? I've read about observables but I'm not 100% sure I'm getting them or if I even need one at this point. I was having problems with things on my page loading before I can tell them where to go which would throw an error.

Anyways here is the call to the backend, which logs out the game data as intended. This is inside my service.

```
  async getAllGames() {
      this.http.get(this.url).subscribe(gameData => {
        console.log(gameData);
        return gameData;
      });
    }
```

But when I call my service function from my other module, it returns undefined.

```
async getGames() {
    const game = await this.games.getAllGames()
    console.log(game);
    _.each(game, (gameData) => {
      this.gamesArray.push(gameData);
    });

    // this.loadCharts(this.gamesArray);

  }
```

Comment: It doesn't "work" in your service either. It just has access to the data inside the async method. If you tried to log that anywhere else in the service you would see the same result. You can not return/extract the data from a subscribe. It will always return an observable, meaning something will happen eventually and subscribe will only "catch" that when it happens. If you want the data, you either need to pass a callback or mutate a variable

Comment: read about subscribe here: https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/guide/subscription

Answer (score 2):

Don't use **`subscribe`** inside service. Just **`return`** an **`Observable`** from service then you can **`subscribe`** to that in any of your components you need.

Change your service code as follows.

```
getAllGames(): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.get(this.url);
}
```

Then you can **`subscribe`** to that **`Observable`** any of your component as follows.

```
this.games.getAllGames()
    .subscribe((res: any) => {
    // TODO: do what you need with response data
});
```

**PS**

If you still need to **`subscribe`** inside service you should **`return`** a **`Promise`**.

```
getAllGames(): Promise<any> {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      this.http.get(this.url).subscribe((res: any) => {
        resolve(res);
      }, (err: any) => {
        reject(err);
      })
   });
}
```

Call the **`Promise`** from any of your components.

```
this.games.getAllGames()
    .then(data => {
        console.log(data);
    })
    .catch(err => console.error(err))
```

**[StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-59185741?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.service.ts)**

Answer (score 1):

I suggest such a solution, allowing you to get data in many components using the same service:

**service:**

```
class APIService { 
    private url: '...'
    public getGames$;

    constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
        this.getGames$ = this.http.get(this.url);
    } 
}
```

**component:**

```
private games;

constructor(private api: APIService) {
    this.service.getGames$.subscribe(games => {
       this.games = games;
    });
}
```